# Can't Enabled Classroom API to project

Tags: google-classroom

I'm trying to Enable Classroom API on my account (This was the email address I used when i signed up). When I click on the link in the directions

Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically enable the API.

https://console.developers.google.com/start/api?id=classroom

I get the error message "The API you requested was not found. Dismiss"

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem with my account. I can now add Classroom API to my apps and the example now works...

Comment: I have the same problem here... Could you, please, share what was the problem with your account?

Comment: It seems my original request was not fully accepted. Just receiving test accounts is not enough. You should be accepted into the program

Comment: The developer preview for the Classroom API is now over and it is open to all developers: http://googleforeducation.blogspot.com/2015/08/general-availability-for-classroom-api.html