# I can't enable Classroom API to project

Tags: google-classroom

I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221022/cant-enabled-classroom-api-to-project) but not properly answered... I can't access the Classroom API in developers console though I've been aproved to do so. Could you, please, share the neccesary steps?

Any help will be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Classroom API is currently in Developer Preview. Please [apply for access](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access) and wait for the confirmation email.

Comment: Hi erick, I already got that confirmation email but it seems developers console is not aware of it :D. As I said "I've been aproved to do so" (Sorry if my english is not 100% correct...).

Comment: Please ensure you are using the same Google account to access the Google Developers Console that you registered with.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I already checked that... And keeps on showing I don't have access to classroom API... (312 stackoverflow points it's not much, but should be enough for making sure of that sort of thing before posting... :-D )

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I received an email with 3 testing accounts (1 with a teacher role and 2 with students role). I get the error message "The API you requested was not found. Dismiss" when I visit classroom api in developers console. I was told in the email to report issues here: "Please ask questions or report issues on Stack Overflow" (though someone probably feels it's a bad idea as he/she downvoted me for this question...). I just want to know if I'm missing something or might be a bug...If you need further information, just let me know.

Comment: The email with the test accounts is not the final confirmation email. Please wait until you receive the final confirmation email before you attempt using the API.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric. The email with the test accounts was sent 7 days ago... We'll be looking forward to get the final one.

Comment: It should have been completed by now. Send my a private message on G+ with your email address and I'll check on your status. google.com/+EricKoleda

Comment: The developer preview for the Classroom API is now over and it is open to all developers: http://googleforeducation.blogspot.com/2015/08/general-availability-for-classroom-api.html

Comment: Thanks, Eric, we are looking forward to use it. Take care!