# can't enable classroom api in console

Tags: google-classroom

This  question is essentially the same as

[Can't Enabled Classroom API to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221022/cant-enabled-classroom-api-to-project)
and 
[I can't enable Classroom API to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288237/i-cant-enable-classroom-api-to-project)

but there isn't a solution on either of these pages.

Our domain has been whitelisted to use the Classroom API (I have had email confirmation) but when I go to the developers console the API is not listed. If I use the wizard from the Google Developers Classroom API Quickstart Page I get 'The API you requested was not found. Dismiss' from within the console.

Does anyone know what is going on or what the solution is?

Many thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You've applied as a domain admin to USE apps that implement the Classroom API but to actually DEVELOP with the Classroom API you need to apply to have your projects white listed. Fill out this form also:

https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1hY4Lk3imYBSOanQHZSqw1AYt9AswVGiltV-Jp7_5QpI/viewform

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I've filled in the form and submitted it, so we'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: The developer preview for the Classroom API is now over and it is open to all developers: http://googleforeducation.blogspot.com/2015/08/general-availability-for-classroom-api.html